# How to properly import matterial in to scene? - python

Tags: python, materials, append

I'm trying to solve this hurdle >

```
import bpy

# path to the blend
filepath = "C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\01_blend_2Mats_mix.blend"

link = False

currentMats = []

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    currentMats.append(mat.name)

print("Current scene materials : ",currentMats)

newMats = []

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
    for material in data_from.materials:
        if material not in currentMats:
            newMats.append(material)
            data_to.materials = material

print("New matterials : ",newMats)
```

Now I got the list of new mats, or at least I think I got, but how can I now import it to the scene?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign `data_from.materials` to `data_to.materials`:

```
import bpy

# Path to the blend
filepath = "//material-library.blend"

mats_current = [m.name for m in bpy.data.materials]

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.materials = [mat for mat in data_from.materials if mat not in mats_current]
```

I recommend use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to verify the actual material count:

```
>>> len(bpy.data.materials)
67
>>> bpy.data.materials['
                        000_Interference Group']
                        1_layer_on_dielectric']
                        2_layers_on_dielectric']
                        3_layers_on_dielectric']
                        AR_glass']
                        Iron_heated_2']
                        Material']
                        STAINEDALUPROC']
                        aluminum_nk']
                        basic_interference_glass']
                        ...
```

API link: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109261/discussion-on-answer-by-brockmann-how-to-properly-import-matterial-in-to-scene).